# Combine command output along with the input

Tags: command-line, pipe, output

I'd like to print command output along with its input. For example for such call as

```
echo "Hello world" | wc -c
```

I want the following output:

```
12,Hello world
```

Is there any way to do this using standard Unix (or GNU) tools?

Comment: Would be good to know if this is for a specific shell or if it should be shell agnostic. Some shells namely have good ways to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tee` and `paste` solution:

```
echo "Hello world" | tee >(wc -c) | tac | paste -s -d, -
12,Hello world
```

Comment: clever solution!

Answer (score 0):

A possibility (I think there should be better ones):

```
echo `echo "Hello world" | wc -c` ",Hello world" | sed 's/ ,/,/g'
```